# How to use backreference multiple times?

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed

dump.data as below:

```
x"xxx":111,"xxxx":2222,xxxx"id":123,xxxxxx"value":321,xxxxxx"id":234,xxxxxx"value":432,xx
x"xxx":yyy,"xxxx":zzz,xxxx"id":223,xxxxxx"value":221,xxxxxx"id":224,xxxxxx"value":232,xxxx....
```

I want to filter only the `id` and `value` info. e.g. After whatever process gives me this:

```
"id":123,"value":321,"id":234,"value":432
"id":223,"value":221,"id":224,"value":232
```

---

What comes to my mind is using backreference, i.e. sed:

```
sed 's|.*\("id":[0-9]*\).*\("value":[0-9]*\).*|\1,\2|' dump.data
```

which gives me this:

```
"id":234,"value":432
"id":224,"value":232
```

But how can I get **all** the id and value info?

Comment: This might help as first step: `grep -o '"[^,]*' dump.data`

Comment: Thanks for your time, question updated. @Cyrus

Comment: This might help as second step: `grep -oE '"(id|value)[^,]*' dump.data`

Comment: Got your point!  Thx! @Cyrus

Comment: and append `| tr '\n' ','` (to replace every newline by a `,`) and as last step find a way to remove trailing `,`.

Comment: @Cyrus What if `dump.data` have multiple line, and I want the result stay in the relative line instead? Q updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplified version from other solutions already presented

```
$ perl -lne 'print join ",", /"[^"]+":\d+/g' dump.data 
"id":123,"value":321,"id":234,"value":432
"id":223,"value":221,"id":224,"value":232
```

- `"[^"]+":\d+` pattern to extract
- `join ","` use `,` as separator to combine the extracted patterns

To capture only `id` and `value`

```
$ perl -lne 'print join ",", /"(?:id|value)":\d+/g' dump.data
"id":123,"value":321,"id":234,"value":432
"id":223,"value":221,"id":224,"value":232
```

- `(?:id|value)` to restrict to only `id` or `value`, but in non-capturing group so that only the entire extracted text is passed onto `join`

Comment: I tried `perl -lne 'print join ",", /"(id|value)":\d+/g' dump.data` which produce `id,value,id,value` only..

Comment: `perl -lne 'print join ",", /("(id|value)":\d+)/g' dump.data` works! I assume print works for `\1` capture?

Comment: are you sure `/("(id|value)":\d+)/g` works?  it will unnecessarily add extra `id` and `value` to output due to `(id|value)`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop to capture a pair at a time, printing each time

```
perl -lne 'print "$1:$2" while /("[^"]+"):(\w+),/g' data.txt
```

You can then redirect it to a file, by adding `> output.txt` to the end of the line.

This outputs one pair per line. To keep each line's pairs on one line

```
perl -nE 'chomp; print "$1:$2," while /("[^"]+"):(\w+),/g; say ""' data.txt
```

This leaves an extra comma after the last pair on the line.  To avoid that

```
perl -lne 'push @m, "$1:$2" while /("[^"]+"):(\w+),/g; print join ",", @m; @m = ()' data.txt
```

This forms the `"$1:$2"` of each pair and adds it to an array. Once the line is processed it prints them joined by `,`. The array is then emptied by `@m = ()` for the next line.

If there may be extra spaces around add `\s*`, like `\s*:\s*`.

Comment: Thx for your time, but this produce the same result as my sed mentioned above.

Comment: @hedleyyan  Fixed

Comment: What if dump.data have multiple line, and I want the result stay in the relative line instead? Q updated. Thx! @zdim

Comment: @hedleyyan  Added another case, a bit more complicated but avoiding the extra comma that the previous one produces after the last pair on the line

Comment: @hedleyyan  glad to do so :)  Seriously, that was my point, instead of trimming it down to one solution -- these can be used in a normal program, and have flexibility (can use different separators, adjust regex for extra patterns, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows

```
perl -ne 'while($_=~m/(?:("id":\d+)|("value":\d+))/g){my $result = $1 // $2; print "$result ";} print "\n";' data.dump
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

try below awk solution -

```
#awk 'BEGIN{FS="x+|y+|z+"} {print  $7,$8,$9,substr($10,1,length($10)-1)}' OFS="" kk.txt
"id":123,"value":321,"id":234,"value":432
"id":223,"value":221,"id":224,"value":232
```

Explanation :

1. `"x+|y+|z+"` : multiple field separator in BEGIN block.
2. `substr($10,1,length($10)-1)` : Remove last character of the column
       which is "`,`" in our case.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
awk -v FPAT='"(id|value)":[0-9]+' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?",":ORS)}' file
"id":123,"value":321,"id":234,"value":432
"id":223,"value":221,"id":224,"value":232
```

Comment: Good one! I don't know FPAT until you .. Thx